# Mobx 'asFlat', 'asReference' not working as expected

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, mobx, ecmascript-next

We are using [Mobx](https://mobx.js.org/getting-started.html) in one of our projects, and I see frequent use of `asFlat` and `asReference` in the code. As per my understanding, `asReference` fires a change only when the reference is changed but not when any property on the object changes. In contrast, Mobx will track all properties of an object marked as `observable` (given that those properties were present during object creation). But I don't see any change in behaviour between the two in the code below.

Similarly, `asFlat` allows the property itself to be observable but not any of its children. Which means that adding a new value to an array marked as `asFlat` will not fire a change, but changing the reference of array will. However, in the code below, both arrays behave exactly the same. Why is this happening?

Also, what is the difference between `asReference` and `asFlat`, as both seem similar?

```
  const {observable, asFlat, asReference, reaction} = mobx;

  class Car {

    constructor() {
      reaction(() => this.colors, () => console.log('colors changed: ',this.colors));
      reaction(() => this.colorsAsFlat, () => console.log('colorsAsFlat changed: ',this.colorsAsFlat));
      reaction(() => this.config, () => console.log('config changed: ',this.config));
      reaction(() => this.configAsReference, () => console.log('configAsReference changed: ',this.configAsReference));
    }

    @observable colors = [];
    @observable colorsAsFlat = asFlat([]);
    @observable config = {model : '7 Series'};
    @observable configAsReference = asReference({model : '7 Series'});
  }

  const bmw = new Car();

  bmw.colors.push('Red');
  bmw.colors[1] = 'Gray';
  bmw.colors = ['Black'];
  bmw.colors.push('Blue');

  bmw.colorsAsFlat.push('Red');
  bmw.colorsAsFlat[1] = 'Gray';
  bmw.colorsAsFlat = ['Black'];
  bmw.colorsAsFlat.push('Blue');

  console.log("Initial Config: ", bmw.config);

  bmw.config.model = '5 Series';
  bmw.config.autopilot = 'true';
  bmw.config = { sunroof : 'true'};

  bmw.configAsReference.model = '5 Series';
  bmw.configAsReference.autopilot = 'true';
  bmw.configAsReference = { sunroof : 'true'};
```

`reaction` is just used to track changes in the observables and will log the observable property whenever it changes. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/dk49/g94fovch/) is a fiddle for the same. Observe the console output for this code.

Questions from above code:

1. Why `bmw.colors.push('Red')` and `bmw.colors[1] = 'Gray'` did not fire a change (reaction)?
2. `bmw.colors = ['Black']` fired the reaction but why does the `colors` array also includes 'Blue' in it in the log when 'Blue' is assigned after 'Black'?
3. `colorsAsFlat` is firing on same changes as `colors` even though it is declared `asFlat`. So it should only fire on `bmw.colorsAsFlat = ['Black']` as its a refernece change (and it does so), but it also unexpectedly includes 'Blue' color. Why so?
4. Why does logging `bmw.config` print `Initial Config: {autopilot: "true", model: "5 Series"}` when these two properties are assigned after the `console.log` statement?
5. Why doesn't reaction fire for `bmw.config.model = '5 Series'`?. Aren't object properties that were present when the observable object was created observed for changes?
6. `configAsReference` is behaving as expected and is firing a change only when the reference is changed; as the reaction fires only on `bmw.configAsReference = { sunroof : 'true'}`, which is a reference change.

Answer (score 0):

1. The reaction will only fire if the data function's return value changes. The default comparison will effectively just do `this.colors === this.colors` and therefore the effect will not run. Try returning `this.colors.length` instead from your data function.
2. Mobx will batch updates in 'transactions' for reasons of performance, so you won't necessarily see a reaction run after every change where multiple happen in the same block of code.
3. Normally when you add elements to an observable array, the new elements are made observable themselves. Using `asFlat` disables this behaviour, but will be unnoticeable when your array elements are just strings.
4. I'm guessing that you're just looking at the expanded object as logged in your console, which probably shows the current value of the object, rather than the value of the object when it was logged. Try logging the individual keys and you should see the values as they were at the time of the logging.
5. Same issue as for question (1). The simple comparison will show no changes - update the data function returning `this.config.model` and you should see a reaction.
6. Not a question.

[The Mobx docs for reactions](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/reaction.html) have some good information. `asReference` and `asFlat` go away in more recent versions, but are equivalent to `observable.ref` and `observable.shallow`. See [the docs](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/modifiers.html) for more information.